# How can I repair this ceiling mounted cloth drying rack?

Tags: repair

I have a cloth drying stand (or cloth drying rack) which is of ceiling mounted type. What happen was that one of the edge fall off and another edge was like hanging up there, waiting to fall off anytime.

The cloth drying stand look similar like the one below:

[image: Hanger]

Is there anyway to fix it? or are there better alternative that is very easy to install on ceiling and is portable (which mean that I can place it anywhere)?

Comment: When you say ends do you mean the parts that go from the clothes stand to the ceiling?

Comment: @lqlarry, Yes, the part from the cloth stand to the ceiling. (not referring to the blue strings but the blue handle. By the way, mime don't have the white metal in between or in the center.

Comment: Show a picture of yours.

Comment: The only thing I can say from seeing the picture and your description is take measurements and see if something like 1/2 EMT (thin wall electrical metallic conduit)in the electrical department at a hardware store will slip over the square tubing and then put some screws in it to keep it from falling apart.  You can get square tubing but it would probably cost too much.

Comment: Actually I feel like removing the whole rack and replace with new ones that are portable and can be mounted on the ceiling. Any ideas which ways is better? - screwing / drilling it back or getting new one that are portable and can be mounted on the ceiling?

Comment: That is completely user preference. How much do you plan on moving it?