# How can I repair this wire clothes drying rack?

Tags: repair

I have a clothes drier, similar to this one, although haven't found a picture from the exact same type.
[image]

Some of the wires/rods came lose:

[image]

What is the easiest/cheapest way to reattach them for long-term? The material is magnetic, so it is probably some kind of steel.

What I thought of:

- some kind of epoxy glue - I don't think there is enough surface for a long-term repair
- spot welding - although there are some cheap spot welders available online, I'm not sure whether spot welders in general are suitable for this material thickness?
- electric welding - I don't know too much about it, would therefore avoid it
- gas welding - although a normal butane handheld torch is certainly not expensive, I'm not sure whether this technique is suitable, and also don't know what else is needed

Comment: In its intended state, does the little rod protrude past the tube, or is it only just long enough?

Comment: Structural adhesive is what you want to look for.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because furniture repair (except woodworking) is off topic here. See the [help].

Comment: A good epoxy weld will cost more than a new dryer. Cut your losses.

Comment: I thought of just wrapping the connection with string or something. Zip tie is even better.

Comment: From the link : This post is hidden. It was deleted 7 years ago by the post author. "**If it's broke buy a new one.** Buy the best most portable one you can afford. Amazon.com has very reasonable prices and many items ship free." – ojait https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/13102/how-can-i-repair-this-ceiling-mounted-cloth-drying-rack?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: For most kinds of welding, it would be cheaper to buy a new rack unless you already have all the equipment.

Comment: I would just use Liquid Nails. It adheres to metals, woods, paints, and most plastics (not all plastics, though), and you have plenty of surface for it to adhere to. Once dried, it'll have a very strong bond. Just clamp it for a day.

Answer (score 6):

You said "easiest/cheapest" but you didn't say "prettiest". So use electric tape in your choice of decorator colors.

You can wrap the tape in a criss-cross pattern. Make the first wrap without stretching the tape much, just to hold things in place, then make additional wraps while stretching the tape strongly. Go around perhaps 10 times while stretching and criss-crossing, and the repair will be incredibly strong. Then make the final 1-2 wraps without stretching and cut to length with scissors. The final relaxed wraps will prevent the repair from unraveling.

Avoid cheap electric tape. It doesn't stretch well and the adhesive will turn to goo after a couple of years. Use professional grade electric tape and the repair will last the rest of your life. And you'll have the rest of the roll remaining for the next bar that breaks off your clothes dryer.

Comment: Good idea and probably the cheapest and easiest to do.  If the other end is done also, almost like a design feature(not really).

Comment: Avoid *all* electric tape that doesn't say Scotch 3M.

Answer (score 5):

Butane/propane torch won't be hot enough. You'd need a dual torch that adds oxygen to the flame for brazing. Cleaning down to bare metal needed.  This should be done in a safe place since you will be working with flame and very hot surfaces, at least for a few minutes.  Good welding gloves and goggles are required.

I would try epoxy welding type (type that has weld in the name) first, but both surfaces/pieces must be cleaned right down to the metal, sanding/grinding and removing all dirt/oils from the surface for best adhesion. I would clean as large an area as possible, not just where the two pieces meet, including above and below where the small rod meets the tube and all around the small rod.

Comment: And the promised +1. ;) Good point about cleaning paint off, but I'm not 100% certain that's needed for epoxy bonding. Definitely best practice, though. Be sure to repaint afterwards to protect bare metal against rusting, especially since it will be in contact/close proximity to wet clothing for much of its life.

Comment: Would MAPP gas work for brazing in this instance?

Comment: @AndrewMorton  I find for brazing the dual tank torches work better.  MAPP plus oxygen will work slightly faster than just plain propane.  Not sure if MAPP alone will get hot enough without using most of a small tank.  The small dual fuel kits are usually not expensive, but are not up to profession use/type for real welding.

Comment: I meant propane plus oxygen, not just propane compared to MAPP/oxygen mix.

Answer (score 3):

That was poorly spot-welded by the manufacturer.

Epoxy (after appropriate cleanup, and perhaps with a wrap of a reinforcing fiber to be bound by the epoxy) will fix it in a "reasonable for somone without a welder" fashion.

It's not a particularly high-stress joint.

While you could seek out a fancy reinforcing fiber, plain old thread, yarn, string, or braided fishing line (monofilament is more difficult to bond reliably) will work fine for this application.

Comment: I would probably use wire, like florist's wire. And then epoxy over it.

Comment: Just drill a hole through the rod and the round strut, and thread some wire through and around the rod and strut.

Comment: Let me get my popcorn so I can watch you try to "just drill a hole" through that rather small rod. Not an easy solution, particularly without significant tooling.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Bring extra for me.  Have a similar dryer stand and those rods might be 1/8 inch in diameter.

Comment: I could drill it if I had to, with what I have at home, but it would be a chore with a solid rod, and pointless.  Instead I'd just use @longneck's solution of wire (thin garden wire in my case) in something like a diagonal lashing pattern.  The wire then take most of the strain with the epoxy only stabilising the joint - you might even be able to use just the wire, until the weld at the other end fails, anyway

Answer (score 1):

MIG welding is becoming less expensive as time progresses. You may be able to visit a local metal shop and expect to pay five dollars or less (possibly free) if you prepare the material in advance and secure it in a temporary manner. This means clearing the paint from the area expected to be welded, both the main frame and the cross rod.

I have a MIG welder and would provide this service at no cost, merely because it is a trivial weld and involves minimal time and materials. Other welder businesses may feel the same.

If you have a makerspace in your area, you may also find a member with a MIG welder willing to do the same.